Generator expressions parsing inside PonyORM
According to the PonyORM docs and some StackOverflow QnA-s (e. g. here), PonyORM performs following action sequence to create SQL query:

Parse Generator Expression,
Parse resultant AST,
Generate SQL query from it.

But I could not find (or understand) any code inside PonyORM, which parses Generator Expressions.
Please, could someone explain underlying magic in generator parsing from within Python?
How can one parse some parts of Python code from the same code?
